# In PHP, how to pass a class instance to another class's constructor

Tags: php

I am trying to make an implementation of the Bridge Design Pattern, following the steps on [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/bridge_pattern.htm). I am converting the code from Java to PHP and changing some names.

The problem is, when I try to pass the concrete bridge implementer class to the concrete class implementing interface, an error is throw.

My code is as follows:

```
// LaunchApi.php
interface LaunchApi
{
    public function launch();
}

// RedEngine.php
class RedEngine implements LaunchApi
{
    public function launch()
    {
        echo "The red engine is really fast!!!";
    }
}

// Rocket.php
abstract class Rocket
{
    protected $launchApi;

    protected function __construct($launchApiImplementer)
    {
        $this->launchApi = $launchApiImplementer;
    }

    public abstract function launch();
}

// FullRocket.php
class FullRocket extends Rocket
{
    public function __construct($launchApi)
    {
        parent::__construct($launchApi);
    }

    public function launch()
    {
        $this->launchApi->launch();
    }
}

// LaunchingScript.php
$redEngine = new RedEngine();
$redEngine->launch(); // this works

$redRocket = new FullRocket($redEngine);
$redRocket.launch(); // this won't work
```

The error throw is:

```
design-patterns\Bridge>php LaunchingBridge.php
The red engine is really fast!!!
Fatal error: Call to undefined function launch() in \design-patterns\Bridge\LaunchingBridge.php on line 24
```

I tried to pass by reference using the &, but it only changes the error.

Comment: Should be `$redRocket->launch();` - i.e. `->` rather than `.`

Comment: A little bit 2 suggestions: 1. Binding interface `LaunchApi` to abstract class `__construct()` method: `__construct(LaunchApi $launchApiImplementer)` to make sure the object you passing in is a implementation of `LaunchApi`. 2. Set abstract class `__construct()` access level public, then you don't need to alias it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah should be `$redRocket->launch();` instead of `$redRocket.launch();`
like what nigel ren said